# How can I set 4 digits date?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

this is my data

```
> x_logit
    Año    Probabilidad      Valor
1  2015 p_c15v_cd_logit 0.08464105
2  2015 p_c15v_tl_logit 0.08700553
3  2015 p_c15v_kp_logit 0.08566559
4  2015 p_c15v_lp_logit 0.08678959
5  2016 p_c16v_cd_logit 0.14655110
6  2016 p_c16v_tl_logit 0.14785441
7  2016 p_c16v_kp_logit 0.14510422
8  2016 p_c16v_lp_logit 0.14735904
9  2017 p_c17v_cd_logit 0.25125131
10 2017 p_c17v_tl_logit 0.24985382
11 2017 p_c17v_kp_logit 0.24634307
12 2017 p_c17v_lp_logit 0.24933684
```

And whenever I try to put the column `Año`as a Date in this format
`> x_logit$Año<-as.Date(x_logit$Año,format="%Y")` I got the dates from 1975.

```
> x_logit
          Año    Probabilidad      Valor
1  1975-10-05 p_c15v_cd_logit 0.08464105
2  1975-10-05 p_c15v_tl_logit 0.08700553
3  1975-10-05 p_c15v_kp_logit 0.08566559
4  1975-10-05 p_c15v_lp_logit 0.08678959
5  1975-10-06 p_c16v_cd_logit 0.14655110
6  1975-10-06 p_c16v_tl_logit 0.14785441
7  1975-10-06 p_c16v_kp_logit 0.14510422
8  1975-10-06 p_c16v_lp_logit 0.14735904
9  1975-10-07 p_c17v_cd_logit 0.25125131
10 1975-10-07 p_c17v_tl_logit 0.24985382
11 1975-10-07 p_c17v_kp_logit 0.24634307
12 1975-10-07 p_c17v_lp_logit 0.24933684
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
structure(list(Año = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Probabilidad = c("p_c15v_cd_logit", 
"p_c15v_tl_logit", "p_c15v_kp_logit", "p_c15v_lp_logit", "p_c16v_cd_logit", 
"p_c16v_tl_logit", "p_c16v_kp_logit", "p_c16v_lp_logit", "p_c17v_cd_logit", 
"p_c17v_tl_logit", "p_c17v_kp_logit", "p_c17v_lp_logit"), Valor = c(0.0846410475493695, 
0.0870055321082446, 0.0856655905826855, 0.0867895859655773, 0.146551098076155, 
0.147854412150009, 0.145104224610706, 0.147359039463159, 0.251251306863531, 
0.249853824276802, 0.246343067372015, 0.249336843631983)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the `class()` of your `Ano` column? What do you get if you run `as.Date("2015", format="%Y")`? A date value needs a month and date, not just year. What month and day do you want to use for these date values? What version of R are you running?

Comment: > class(x_logit$Año)
[1] "numeric"

Comment: It's an aggregate value, it does represent the whole year, so I don't really need the month or day. Weeks ago this code was working just fine

Comment: I'm sorry but dates in R can't have just a year. In the case where the value is numeric like `as.Date(2015, format="%Y")` you should be getting an error "'origin' must be supplied". Do you have any non-base R packages loaded that define an `as.Date` function?

Comment: Yes, I've got zoo and lubridate

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the years to character:

```
x_logit$Año <- as.character(x_logit$Año)
```

Then use `format` twice:

```
format(as.Date(x_logit$Año, format = "%Y"), "%Y")
```

The first `format`(inside `as.Date`) serves to identify the format the data is already in; the second serves to re-format the data into the desired format

Comment: All the years went back to 1975

Comment: Can you use `dput()` to post some of your data in reproducible form?

Comment: Done! Thanks for helping

Comment: Just changed right now, sorry

Comment: Did this help, Jorge?

Comment: If your goal is to create a character version of year, the second step seems redundant. `str(as.character(2015))`; `str(format(as.Date(as.character(2015), "%Y"), "%Y"))`...